# How to check whether all records have the same value in a field?

Tags: sql

Apologies for the newbie question.

I have data that looks like this:

```
ID|SubID|Category
1|1|Fixed
1|2|Fixed
2|1|Unfixed
2|2|Unfixed
3|1|Fixed
4|1|Unfixed
5|1|Fixed
5|2|Unfixed
```

I need to know all the IDs where the Category is "Fixed" for all SubIDs (i.e. I'd want the query to return IDs 1 and 3).

How can I do this?

An an extension, I need to know all the IDs where the Category contains a mix of "Fixed" AND "Unfixed" for all SubIDs (i.e. I'd want the query to return just ID 5).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `group by` + `having` clause.

> I need to know all the IDs where the Category is "Fixed" for all SubIDs

```
select id
  from tablename
 group by id
 having count(*) = count(case when Category = 'Fixed' then 'X' end)
```

> I need to know all the IDs where the Category contains a mix of "Fixed" AND "Unfixed" for all SubIDs

```
select id
  from tablename
 group by id
 having count(distinct Category) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Return an ID if there exists no row with that ID which is unfixed:

```
select distinct ID
from tablename t1
where not exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                  where t2.id = t1.id 
                    and t2.Category = 'Unfixed')
```

Problem 2, mixed fixed and unfixed:

```
select id
from tablename
group by id
having max(Category) <> min(Category)
```

I.e. of two different Categories for an ID, return the id.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy to do with an `EXISTS`.

(For those with only `Fixed`)

```
Select  Distinct T.ID
From    Table   T
Where Not Exists
(
    Select  *
    From    Table   T2
    Where   T2.ID = T.ID
    And     T2.Category = 'Unfixed'
)
And Exists
(
    Select  *
    From    Table   T2
    Where   T2.ID = T.ID
    And     T2.Category = 'Fixed'
)
```

For a mix of both:

```
Select  Distinct T.ID
From    Table   T
Where Exists
(
    Select  *
    From    Table   T2
    Where   T2.ID = T.ID
    And     T2.Category = 'Fixed'
)
And Exists
(
    Select  *
    From    Table   T2
    Where   T2.ID = T.ID
    And     T2.Category = 'Unfixed'
)
```