# How to check if all instances of a DB row are the same and if so count + 1 in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite, count

I have the following SQLite DB table:

```
app | vendor | active
---------------------
123 |  AGX   | 1
123 |  OTMA  | 0
123 |  PEI   | 0

255 |  IYU   | 0
255 |  MAG   | 0
255 |  MEI   | 0

675 |  IUU   | 0
675 |  AGU   | 0
675 |  O3I   | 0
```

I need to be able to run a query to find out out of these apps, which ones have *NO active vendors*.

In the above example, `app 255` and `app 675` have no active vendors (0), therefore the return of my query should be `2`.

So far, I am only able to run a query to get the number of rows that are 'false', but not the number of apps which are false in ALL instances:

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM app_vendor WHERE active = 0`

**summing up: if all rows of a single app are 'false', that should add 1 to the count.**

Comment: that's why uber has so high prices :D. You can group by App and select only where MAX(active) == 0... if active is a bit column

Comment: and yes, please let us know what exactly sql are you using... MSSQL, MySQL...?

Comment: I'm using SQLite. It is indeed a bit column (I've edited the question to reflect that). Would you please provide the full query? can be added as the answer.

Comment: how does grouping by 'app' work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check whether all records have the same value in a field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32741158/how-to-check-whether-all-records-have-the-same-value-in-a-field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will give you a list of apps with NO active vendors:

```sql
SELECT app
FROM app_vendor
GROUP BY app
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN active = true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

To count the records you could wrap it in a subquery:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
  SELECT app
  FROM app_vendor
  GROUP BY app
  HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN active = true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
      SELECT app, COUNT(*)
      FROM demo
      GROUP BY app
      HAVING MAX(active) = 0
)
```

So basically you create groups of your vendors by app and then check if in group the max value is false (it means true isn't present).

There should be more elegent way for it indeed.

Comment: I think this is almost there! It's returning many rows but not a final count of all the apps that have active = 0 in all of their instances

Comment: oh, understood... it's returning like count for each app

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you have an `app` table with one row per `app`.  I would recommend using this:

```
select a.*
from app a
where not exists (select 1
                  from app_vendor av
                  where av.app = a.app and av.active = 1
                 );
```

This approach has two advantages to just using the `app_vendor` table itself:

1. By avoiding the outer aggregation, it is likely to be faster under many circumstances.
2. It will return apps that have no vendors.

Answer (score 0):

You need aggregation and `COUNT()` window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) OVER() AS counter
FROM app_vendor
GROUP BY app
HAVING MAX(active) = 0
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=44937e948be697363f9154f4cdc8923d).
Results:

| counter |
| --- |
| 2 |